# Google analytics - Campaign Code parameter

Tags: android, google-analytics

In google analytics dashboard, does anyone knows what **Campaign Code** parameter stands for and how to set its value?

[image]

I have looked in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#cn) and found no mention of this parameter.
Also, other parameters, for example, **Event Category**, have the **?** sign next to them that opens a bubble with some description which **Campaign Code** parameter does not have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=traffic_sources&jump=ga_campaigncode

> For manual campaign tracking, it is the value of the utm_id campaign tracking parameter.